# For each node I want to draw arrow '->'

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

I want to draw '->' for each path.

Actually I tried to add every node option and '->', but this doesn't work.

I know that \draw[->] (t1)--(t2); \draw[->] (t2)--(t3); ... would be work.

But I want to know simple solution.

Is there any simple solution?

[image]

```
\begin{figure} \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, block/.style = {rectangle, draw}]
\matrix[every node/.style = block, column sep=4mm, row sep=6mm]{    
        \node (t1) {host}; & & \node (t11) {host}; \\
        \node (t2) {ICMP}; & & \node (t10) {ICMP}; \\
        \node (t3) {ICMP}; & & \node (t9) {ICMP}; \\ 
        \node (t4) {host}; & & \node (t8) {host}; \\ 
        \node (t5) {ICMP}; & \node (t6) {dd}; & \node (t7) {ICMP}; \\ 
    }; 
    \path[draw, every node, ->] (t1)--(t2)--(t3)->(t4)->(t5)->(t6)->(t7)->(t8)->(t9)->(t10);
    \end{tikzpicture} \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path is treated as a single object and therefore the segments themselves can't have arrows.  But you can easily draw the path in a loop, and then each segment can have its own arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, block/.style = {rectangle, draw}]
\matrix[every node/.style = block, column sep=4mm, row sep=6mm]{    
        \node (t1) {host}; & & \node (t11) {host}; \\
        \node (t2) {ICMP}; & & \node (t10) {ICMP}; \\
        \node (t3) {ICMP}; & & \node (t9) {ICMP}; \\ 
        \node (t4) {host}; & & \node (t8) {host}; \\ 
        \node (t5) {ICMP}; & \node (t6) {dd}; & \node (t7) {ICMP}; \\ 
    };
    \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 1)] in {2,...,11}{
    \path[draw, ->] (t\lastx)--(t\x);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]